Understanding 良いって人だけ
I am uncertain about the meaning of 良いって人だけ below

誰かに愛されてもそれに何かを返す事はない
それでも良いって人だけ好きになってくれたら良い

I think the last sentence means "even so, it is fine if anyone takes liking of me because I am a good person"? I interpret this だけ as だけに, meaning "because." Is that right?

Unfortunately you've made parsing errors around それでも and だけ.

それでも良い is "(even) that is fine".
って right after it is a colloquial version of という.
This だけ is not だけに. が is omitted after だけ.

So:

それでも良い
that's fine
「それでも良い」って(いう)人
those who are okay with that
「それでも良い」って人だけ(が)(私を)好きになってくれたら良い。
If those who are okay with that like me, that's enough.

それ refers to the previous sentence.
